# How is the strike going to impact PLDI?

Tags: discussion, moderation

With the ongoing [moderation strike](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/389811/moderation-strike-stack-overflow-inc-cannot-consistently-ignore-mistreat-an), a large quantity of users (including myself) have decided to refrain from moderation activities such as flagging and close-voting.

How will this affect PLDI due to it being a beta site? Will PLDI lose a lot of main contributors?

Comment: Hopefully, as little as possible. When organizing the strike, we decided not to abandon sites in beta, as not to kill it.

Comment: I thought the strike was largely limited to diamond mods?

Comment: @BruceAdams Some people who aren't mods are choosing not to flag/VTC posts in solidarity.

Answer (score 5):

Regardless of the strike, I haven't needed to flag any comments or posts so far, and I might have voted to close one or two questions but those were earlier when we had less of an idea of what questions were on-topic.

Maybe this will change assuming we graduate to public beta, but I think even if a significant number of strikers decide to avoid moderation activities here, my guess is that it won't have much impact on the site. Relatively little moderation needs to be done here compared to other sites.

Answer (score 2):

Most strikers, myself included, are **against striking on private beta sites** because this can cause them to be shutdown. Also, SE makes little money from them.